# how to redirect to a specific tab in another page using react

Tags: reactjs, redirect

```
<button onClick={()=>history.push("/page")}> Redirect </button>
```

code for /page component:

```
const[toggle,setToggle] = useState<boolean>(true);

 return(
    <div>{toggle? <Tab1Container /> : <Tab2Container />} </div>
 )
```

there are 2 different tabs on /page, lets say tab1 and tab2, by default when you loading /page, it shows tab1 component. How can I redirect to tab2 component when I click on the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Link and useLocation from react-router-dom to achieve the result you want. It can be used as:

You can use the following code on the page where the button is present.

```
   import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: '/page',
          state: {
            toggleValue: false
          }
        }}
      >
   <button onClick={()=>history.push("/page")}> Redirect </button>
  </Link>
```

On the page component

```
       import {useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

         const location = useLocation()
         const { toggleValue } = location?.state ?? {}

          const[toggle,setToggle] = useState<boolean>(toggleValue);

             return(
             <div>{toggle? <Tab1Container /> : <Tab2Container />} </div>
              )
```

Also, you can set toogle value on useEffect hook when page load and to change the tab on page use setToggle on handle function

Comment: A useLocaton hook is a function that returns the location object that contains information about the current URL. A location object has properties like hash, pathName, and state. You can get the current url from pathName and extra information from the link from state.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what problem you are facing. If you are having trouble setting toggle to toggleValue, you can use the useEffect hook when the page loads. useEffect(()=>{ setToggle(toggleValue)},[]) or you can pass toggleValue as dependency

Comment: Hi Ganesh, I am facing a new issue with this method. It is not working when I am on Tab1Container and when I click that redirect button, it will not redirect me to Tab2Container. But it is working when I am on other pages. I know it's been a long time, but can u plz help? Appreciate it

Comment: Can you explain more clearly?

Comment: yes, so given I am under tab1 on /page, when I click the redirect button, it will not redirect me to tab2. (just to be clear, the redirect button is on a header component which appears on every page)

Answer (score 0):

Just uplift the useState of the toggle Button or use context api or state management libraries..

From your parent component..

Pass SetToggle as props to the button component &
Pass toggle as props to the Page Component

```
<button onClick={()=>setToggle(!toggle)}> Redirect </button>
```

For your reference,

https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html